# SSIS change datetime variable to other format

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ADO.NET Source in my SSIS package, and im trying to make the following query:

"SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateAdded >  '@[User::InputDateV]'"

For other hand i have a DateTime variable called InputDateV.

My issue is that in the variable value i can use the following date: 24/10/2012 but my Sql server this date is not valid and should be 10/24/2012.

How i can i change the datetime  format of my variable to be (mm/dd/yyyy)?

Thanks.

Regards.

Jose.

Comment: You might find [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697584/ssis-flow-ado-net-source-task-with-parameter) interesting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The safest bet is to convert your DateTime variable into the ISO date format:

```
"'" + (DT_WSTR,4)YEAR(@[User::InputDateV]) 
    + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)MONTH(@[User::InputDateV]),2)
    + RIGHT("0" + (DT_WSTR,2)DAY(@[User::InputDateV]),2) 
    + "'"
```

This evaluates to '20121024' and as such is a perfect, unambiguous date string for SQL Server.

Comment: YYYY-MM-DD is not unambiguous: try 2012-13-11 with French language and see what happens. Per [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx), the unambiguous ISO8601 formats are either `YYYYMMDD` (time is optional) or `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss[.mmm]` (only milliseconds are optional). So you should remove the dashes from your example.

Comment: We always use the 'YYYYMMDD', no idea why did I make it more complicated then it was needed. At the end, we all learn something. Thanks! The code has been changed.

Comment: I confirm the above approach works, as I am using it in an SSIS package now. Basically you chop up the DateTime variable into its elements and rebuild it as YYYYMMDD as milivojevi explains. But it is strange - if you use the DT_WSTR cast to convert GETDATE() to a string it comes out YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss, but if you use DT_WSTR to convert an SSIS DateTime variable it comes out DD/MM/YYYY. It's almost like the result of GETDATE() is stored using a different type than SSIS DateTime. Anyway, the above answer works.

Answer (score 1):

A datetime datatype has no format. When you convert it to a string type, then yes, you can apply a locale aware format but internally a datetime is locale agnostic.

I'll preface my response with the ADO.NET source is far more painful than the OLE counterpart.

In my reproduction, I have an Execute SQL Task that creates a table and sticks some data in it. It then routes to a data flow task.

[image]

Within my data flow, I start with a query of `SELECT T.* FROM dbo.[Table] AS T`. There is no WHERE clause currently. This is here to allow the data flow components to register the meta data of the source query.

[image]

To parameterize it, you need to go back to the Control Flow level. Select the Data Flow Task and under Properties, you will need to add an Expression for the SqlCommand property of the ADO NET source.

It has been my experience that one is better served building expressions on variable and assigning a variable into a Task's property versus creating it in the Task itself. If for no other reason, this approach allows you to set a breakpoint and view your locals and visually inspect the value. This cannot be done on an object's expression - especially if said expression is causing the package to fail.

To this end, you will see I have defined two variables in my SSIS package.

- InputDateV - Data type is DateTime and it has a value of `10/24/2012 12:01 AM` I added a time component simply to display it but you can strip that off as suits your needs.
- Query - Data type is String. This variable's properties are EvaluateAsExpression = True and the Expression is `"SELECT T.* FROM dbo.[Table] T WHERE T.DateAdded > '" + (DT_WSTR, 24)@[User::InputDateV] + "'"`  Here I force the locale agnostic datetime value into a locale aware type but because it's through the magic of .NET code, it'll work.

I then use @[User::Query] to configure [ADO NET Source].[SqlCommand] and magically, everything works.

On the off chance I misunderstood your definition above with regard to your variable names. If @[User::InputDateV] is actually a type of String, then the above is not going to work for you. I created a variable, @[User::InputDateS] of data type string and assigned it a value of `24/10/2012`. If I modify the @[User::Query] expression to use it, SQL Server will reject it as it can't make that value into a datetime data type. So make the SSIS expression perform the translation. Modify the expression on @[User::Query] to be
`"SELECT T.* FROM dbo.[Table] T WHERE T.DateAdded > '" + (DT_WSTR, 24)((DT_DATE) @[User::InputDateS]) + "'"` and Bob's your uncle, green boxes across the package.

### Reference

- [How do I use parameters in an SSIS ADO NET source?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/04/11/forum-faq-how-do-i-use-parameters-in-an-ssis-ado-net-source.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can have the SSIS string variable and Save the value in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. Value passed to prepare the query has the single quotes('), so that will work. If you want to maintain with the SSIS date time, prepare the query using the script component using System.DateTime as follows. then your query will be prepared. Hope this helps.

```
public void Main()
{
  // Map your variable using Dts.Variables["NameOfDateTimeVariable"].Value
  DateTime dt= DateTime.Now;

  var dateTime = string.Format("{0:mm/dd/yyyy}",dt);

  var query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM Table WHERE DateAdded > '{0}'",dateTime);

  //Map the query to your variable if you want

 Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
}
```

Thanks,
Gowdhaman

Comment: Hi Godhaman, thanks for your reply probably is a stupid question but i cannot see the code behind my ADO.Net source. I just can see visual studio editor for data flows. How i can see the source code?