# How can I use a variable in a data source?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am transferring a very large table that has a column called EndOfSessionTime and I would like to get a var `LastSess=MAX(EndOfSessionTime)` from the destination and transfer only rows `WHERE EndOfSessionTime > LastSess`.

I set the variable using a ScriptTask in the control flow, but I can't seem to find a straight-forward way to use the variable in a data source.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12697584/ssis-flow-ado-net-source-task-with-parameter) and [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/04/11/forum-faq-how-do-i-use-parameters-in-an-ssis-ado-net-source.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 options:

1)   Stuff your entire SQL Query into a variable, and in the OLEDB Data Source, choose "SQL Command From a Variable"

2)  Use parameters in your SQL query.  Indicate a placeholder for a parameter with a Question Mark character, and then hop over to the Parameters tab to assign the variable to the parameter.   Google "SSIS Data Source Parameters" for tutorials and examples.

Answer (score 0):

To use connection parameters is a must in SSIS, but I had a heck of a time to find how. Microsoft made up a word "Parametrization" and using it as a search term seems to be the only way to come up with how.

The connection manager names at the bottom of the SSIS desktop are actual objects. Right-clicking on one and selecting "Parametrization" is how connection parameters are set. One more note on that: There is no "Apply" on this dialog, so set one paramter at a time, OK, then right-click-Parametrize again. If you set a parameter and go on to the next one without clicking OK, the first one will be lost.